# If a square matrix A is negative definite, is it true that I-(A^T)A is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A question in my linear algebra mock exam asks if the following is true: "Let A be an n by n matrix with complex entries and let I be the n by n identity matrix. If A is negative definite, then I-(A^T)A is invertible," where A^T is the transpose of A.

If A is negative definite, then by the definition in my lecture notes,  A is self-adjoint, so by the self-adjoint spectral theorem A=UDU* where U is unitary, U* is the adjoint of U and D is diagonal. Also, A is negative definite if and only if all eigenvalues of A are strictly negative, so the entries along the diagonal of D are negative. But where do I go from here?

Comment: Isn't $A=(-1)I$ a counterexample, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @79037662, your examples is correct and so is for every real unitary $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. Consider the 2x2 matrices and let $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Its eigenvalues are all $-1$, and this matrix is Hermetian. Therefore it is negative definite.

We have $$I-A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
which is clearly not invertible.

Comment: So this question was part of a question that asked how many out of 4 statements are true, and the answer is that 3 of the statements are true. The other 3 statements were: "If A is positive definite, then A is invertible," "If A is positive semidefinite, then I+A is invertible" and "If A is indefinite, then I+A is positive definite." I thought the statements about positive definite and positive semidefinite were true, and the statement about indefinite was false. So I guess I've gone wrong somewhere with one of the other statements?

Comment: @Jake_2001 Guess so. If you want to ask about which of those you got wrong, I suggest asking another question here on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more interesting counterexample. Let
$$
B=\pmatrix{1&i\\ -i&2}\text{ so that }B^TB=\pmatrix{1&-i\\ i&2}\pmatrix{1&i\\ -i&2}=\pmatrix{0&-i\\ -i&3}.
$$
$B$ is positive definite, as it is Hermitian and its eigenvalues are $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Incidentally, $B^TB$ has the same spectrum as $B$'s. Therefore, if we put $A=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pm\sqrt{5}}}B$, then $A$ is negative definite and $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$. Hence $I-A^TA$ is singular.